# Split string in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Good day,

I need all the values in the string to be displayed in the form roll.

In one table there is a code number (ID)1 -> (name) Brno, (ID) 2 -> (name) Pilsen, etc.

I will extract the ID and Name from this table (number table), but I want to display only the values that match the name in the second table.

The second table consists of the tour ID and then the boarding column where the whole chain Prague, Pilsen, Ostrava is for each tour ID, there are different boarding points

The problem is that I don't know how to split the string so that it matches the name from the dialer.

```
function pine_dynamic_select_field_values ($scanned_tag, $replace) {  
    $string =  $_GET["z"];
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $scanned_tag['name'] != 'nastup1' )  
        return $scanned_tag;
$str= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT nastup FROM `4w_zajezd` WHERE ID = '$string' ");
    $str = explode(',', $str); 
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results(     
        "select ID,nazev from 4w_nastup where nazev in (SELECT nastup FROM 4w_zajezd  WHERE ID = '".$_GET["z"]."' )"
    );
    
     if ( !$rows )  
        return $scanned_tag;
    
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
                $scanned_tag['raw_values'][] = $row-> ID . '|' . $row->nazev;
            
            }
     
    $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($scanned_tag['raw_values']);

    $scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_befores();
    $scanned_tag['labels'] = $pipes->collect_afters();
    $scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes;
  
    return $scanned_tag;  
}  

add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'pine_dynamic_select_field_values', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Split what exactly? Also, there is a serious problem with your code. Please read, and understand: [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Are you storing data in a comma delimited list?